# How do I delete data from a large-volume custom object in Sandbox

Tags: soql, sandbox, filters

**We have a Sandbox environment with storage limit 2 GB, while alone Order_item__c storage amount is 1.8 GB.**

We are trying to delete the record using the filter **Year<=2013** from Order_item__c module. How do we deal with mass deletion of records with based on year filter using workbench?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a one time batch and execute it using anonymous window in dev console.

Comment: Can you provide an example to show how this would be done? The asnwer isn't much use on it's own!

Answer (score 1):

You might probably want to refresh your existing sandbox and use [Sandbox templates](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_sandbox_templates.htm&language=en_US):

> Sandbox templates allow you to pick specific objects and data to copy
>   to your Full or Partial Copy sandbox to control the size and content
>   of each sandbox. Sandbox templates are only available for use with
>   Full or Partial Copy sandboxes.
>
> When you create a sandbox template, you select the object data
>   (standard and custom) to copy during the creation or refresh of a
>   sandbox.

If you don't want to refresh the sandbox now, you could go with one of the below options:

1. Run a one-time batch job to delete the records you want. This will require Apex coding.
2. Run a query in the data loader to fetch all the records you wish to delete and then perform the delete operation using the data loader.

Answer (score 1):

You can operate on the results of a SOQL query. Would be simple enough to query using `SELECT Id FROM Order_item__c WHERE Year<=2013`. Be certain to use the proper field names of course.

**Edit**

Its been to run that as anonymous APEX using something like

```
DateTime MyDT = DateTime.newInstance(2012, 31, 12, 24, 59, 59);
list<Order_item__c>mylist=[SELECT ID FROM Order_item__c WHERE CreatedDate <=: MyDT  Limit 10000] ;   
Delete mylist;
```

Comment: We give our try on soql :SELECT Id FROM Order_Item__c WHERE CALENDAR_YEAR(CreatedDate) <= 2013 then WE want to delete this ID's FROM delete option of workbench.

Comment: See my edited answer with suggestions.

Comment: @crmprogev We have deleted the  the  data<=2015 . we have to take care of current Year data that is 2016 only it constitute 1.7 GB alone. We have constraint that full sandbox  should be copy of production. and it is mandatory to keep  current Year records. We are finding the  way  to  deal with  this situation. Your time is always  valuable for me.Thanks.

Comment: isn't the DML limit on records per transaction 10,000?

Comment: @cropredy. Yes, indeed it is. The limit on records returned in a SOQL query is 50k, thus the reason I specified that limit. If more than 10k are returned, they could use a for loop to delete the records in 10k chunks. They can't query more than 50k records & delete at the same time unless they write a SOQL for loop. In that situation, I believe it would occur in batches of 200 records.

Comment: Hmm.  The transaction limit is 10000 DML records.  The for loop wouldn't help if 50000 records were retrieved.

Comment: Wasn't thinking of it in terms of being a limit per execution context, but instead as a limit per transaction. You're absolutely correct that more than one 10k transaction would exceed a platform limit. 10k records of total DML is an execution context limit, not a single record transaction DML limit. Good catch!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if Year is a custom field. You will need to run this script (or a similiar script) in the Developer Console. Create a list to gather the records you want to delete, then delete that list.

```
//Create List of Desired Records to Delete
List<Order_item__c> delLst = [SELECT id FROM Order_item__c WHERE Year__c <= 2013 LIMIT 50000] ;
//Delete List
delete delLst;
```

Comment: Problem  is we just had <10k records  captured in <=2013 but 879235 records fall in 2016  that means  1.7 GB still to  be deleted. But we want to keep this year records. Question is  i am  bit confused with  process of what to delete in this case for currrent Year

Comment: Change the script to "List<Order_item__c> delLst = [SELECT id FROM Order_item__c WHERE Year__c != 2016 LIMIT 50000] ;
delete delLst;". You will now only delete records where their year is not equal to 2016. I do not full understand your comment. Why are you using the sandbox to stores these record? Just export them out and save them for future use.

Comment: Ok I am going to make try on it

Comment: It is saying  no such record for  !=2016 limit 50000

Comment: You need to determine which field you are using for your date and use that field instead. I used Year__c as an example. Is it the Created Date standard field?

Comment: @Why are you using the sandbox to stores these record? Just export them out and save them for future use. : so shall we  delete Complete  table after exporting or keep few record for testing purpose only

Comment: Yes i am using  filter on WHERE CALENDAR_YEAR(CreatedDate) != 2016 Limit 50000

Comment: Use "CALENDAR_YEAR(CreatedDate) <= 2015-12-31T23:03:35.000Z". This should get all records where they were made before almost midnight Dec-31-2015. You might need to run it several times to get all the records gathered and deleted since you can only gather 50000 at a time.

Comment: We will try  on this and get back to you in short time. thanks

Comment: When i tried it gives me sorry no record found as output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37821/discussion-between-vickps-and-mercury86).

Comment: I sorry I cannot use chat right now. You should have all the tools you need to solve this problem. Deleting records is well documented. Make sure you are in the right sandbox (your sandbox may very well be empty if it is a dev sandbox).

Comment: Our type is FULL sandbox

Comment: Thanks for Helping on  the  issue. We will try to  make more empty.